# Initialise static pointers in class

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to initialise static pointers as arrays inside a class definition, but getting runtime errors. I've seen examples where something similar is done, but I can't get it working, and not sure why. Some example code I've tried is:

```
class Header
{
private:
    static int *pointer;
public:
    int getVal(int val);
};
```

Class definition:

```
#include "Header.h"

int* Header::pointer = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

int Header::getVal(int val)
{
    return pointer[val];
}
```

main:

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Header header;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << header.getVal(i);
    }
}
```

Running this causes an error while initialising the pointer. If I run through it in the debugger, and ignore the error, I can see that the pointer is initisalised with 0 at the beginning. If I then continue to step through it I get another error saying the heap's been corrupted. Is it possible to intitialise a pointer in this way? If not, are there any suggestions on how one can initialise a member variable pointer into an array, and assign it values, inside the class definition without having to assign each element of the array individually.

Comment: why don't you use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead?

Comment: When you say, "Running this causes an error while initialising the pointer", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: nijansen, to be honest, I don't know why I'm not using one of them, I assumed it would be simple enough, and wouldn't need the extra functionality. And now I would just like to know if this is possible.
NPE, what I mean is that as the debugger passes over the line "int* Header::pointer = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};", VS comes comes with a window saying it's triggered a breakpoint; which may not actually be considered an error, now that I think about it.

Comment: Looking at the grammar, I think you *need* to provide the size in the brackets for the array-form of new `new int[5] {0,1,2,3,4}`

Comment: GCC 4.8.1 doesn't compile if the array size isn't specified. When it is specified as in DyP's comment, it gives the expected result.

Comment: As an aside, do you really want this to be static?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably get away with:

```
class Header
{
public:
    int getVal(int valIndex);
};
```

and then

```
#include "Header.h"

static int s_vals[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}; // could move this line to B

int Header::getVal(int valIndex)
{
    // B
    return s_vals[valIndex];
}
```

Considering that you know the size of the array at compile time and there is no need to advertise an implementation detail if you are providing accessors anyway.

Comment: Probably `static int s_vals[] = {0,1,2,3,4};` (for internal linkage). Another way: `int Header::getVal(int p) { static const int s_vals[] = {0,1,2,3,4}; return s_vals[valIndex]; }` (if you don't need to change the contents).

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that your compiler simply does not support braced-init-list.
If so you can rewrite your class the following way

```
class Header
{
private:
    static int *pointer;
    static int *init()
    {
        int *p = new int[5];
        std::iota( p, p + 5, 0 ); 
        return ( p );
    }             
public:
    int getVal(int val);
};
```

And then pointer is defined the following way

```
int * Header::pointer = Header::init();
```

Comment: Once you delegate the creation to a function, you could use `static int *init() { static int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4}; return arr; }` instead. That's aggregate-initialization, and already supported in C++98 (and previous versions, it comes from C).

Comment: Surely, if " compiler simply does not support braced-init-list" we'd get a compile error?